# Find IE-breaking ECMAScript/JavaScript errors

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer, jslint, google-closure-compiler

I work on a relatively huge ECMAScript codebase (> 60,000 LOC) and we tend to struggle a bit with detecting errors for our dreaded friend Internet Explorer (especially 6 and 7).

At the moment, I've been stuck with an issue for 3 days where my RIA renders fine in Google Chrome, Firefox 3.6, Opera and Internet Explorer 8, but fails when running Internet Explorer 8 in IE7-Mode (or with a real IE-7).

My question really is: how do you do to identify code that will produce an error in IE7?

Usually I rely on JSLint and I tend to catch the usual suspects (trailing commas, I loathe you), but in this particular case I have just re-run a linter on all my code, both source and minimized, and it doesn't yield my usual suspects. So I guess I have mistakenly introduced something that IE doesn't like (who knows, maybe I got crazy and used Array.map instead of dojo.map somewhere?) and it blows up in my face, producing nice error messages that don't help me at all ("[object object]" and " is null" where it shouldn't be, so I assume there was an error up-stream that failed silently and prevented this object from being created).

I've tried having a look at the Google Closure Linter but it doesn't yield anything special, and I don't think that the Google Closure Compiler is going to be my savior either. is there any tool (command-line, web-service or other) that can parse/run code as if it were emulating IE so we can get the appropriate errors?

Any tips are appreciated.

EDIT: Thank you for your help in trying to solve my issue so far, but what I am really just asking is if there are tools that do this sort of checks, meaning validating a feature set and syntax against a particular browser. This is the sort of thing severly lacking in the JS-world in my opinion (not so much for FF or Chrome, obviously as their debuggers are a bit more helpful).

EDIT2: I eventually found the root of my problem today (after 3 days) by going through all my code changes between two branches and realizing that the problem was actually already there but never detected before and going back through even older changes to narrow down the mess and eventually end up adding console logs everywhere until I reached a point of failure (God thank emacs for its regular expression support to add logs to every single line... heavy but works...). Fun fact though: IE swallowed an error message supposed to be displayed in the try catch block originally catching the source problem and then re-throwing it. Still don't why, but if it hadn't then that would have been a lot easier to find, as it was intended for that purpose in case it broke. Weird. Might not like deep-levels of re-throw.

I'll leave the question open as for now there are no answer to the actual question.

Comment: When you run in IE8 in good old IE7 mode and you open up the debugging console, do you have the wonderful break on errors button checked so it will point at where the error is occurring?

Comment: JSLint and the Closure complier are more about syntax issues than Browser X does not support Y method.

Comment: @epascarello: yes, except it points to one of our throw statements, and then going through the stacktrace to show what we threw doesn't pinpoint anything. Plus it doesn't seem to be specific to this file: if I change the order of the files launched at bootstrap, it will fail somewhere on whichever is first. I know about JSLint and Closure not doing this, but usually the main browser-dependant issue is the trailing comma for IE7, and they do help to catch this. Won't help much with anything else, granted.

Comment: @epascarello: actually, it pinpoints as mentioned earlier a line where an object (the package namespace to an object, really) is said to be null (because it is in that case, but shouldn't be. But no other errors thrown before... except the console does still show just an "[object object]" message in red before this particular error, but without breaking on it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try the IE8 debugger, as @galambalazs suggests; the old debugger from the IE6 era was generally not useful.

The low-level technique I've always used is to add my own try/catch blocks around large portions of the my Javascript source to narrow down the source of error.  By iteratively adjusting your try/catch blocks you can do a "binary search" through your source to locate the code that's causing an exception.  What you'll probably find is that there's some code that's harmless in Firefox but which IE's interpreter considers an error. (To be fair, it's *usually* the case that IE's strictness is justified, and that the lax behavior of Firefox is really undesirable.)

So in other words, you'd start on a Javascript source that you suspect, or perhaps you'd do this to all of your included .js files:

```
// top of Javascript source file foo.js
try {
  // ... all the code ...
} catch (x) { alert("Error in foo.js: " + x); }
```

Now, if you load the page and get that alert, then you know that the error is somewhere in foo.js.  Thus, you split it in half:

```
// top of foo.js
try {
  // ... half the code, roughly ...
}
catch (x) { alert("Error in first half of foo.js: " + x); }
try {
  // ... the rest of the code ...
} catch (x) { alert("Error in second half of foo.js: " + x); }
```

Repeat that process and you'll eventually find the problem.

Comment: Not really looking forward to a b-tree search of >60,000 lines, honestly :)

Comment: By ten or so iterations you'll probably start to suspect where the problem is.

Comment: `window.onerror` would get you closer without a try/catch block.  `window.onerror = function (msg, url, line) { alert("Error on line "+ line); }`

Comment: @Pointy: that, along with the `url` argument, was highly unreliable in IE 7 and lower but all my experiences with IE 8 (and I've written an onerror stack tracer) tell me that this is fixed, except for the very rare occasion that it is a single line off the mark.

Comment: @Andy E yes I agree that IE8 is (mostly) all fixed up in that regard, but the question is about IE7, or IE7 mode.  If IE8 doesn't emulate that particular IE7 feature (I've never tried it), then you're right and that'd be a much quicker approach. However, it might be quicker still to lean on the IE8 debugger directly!!

Comment: @Pointy: indeed, the built-in tools should be good enough. On a side note, IE 8 in 7 mode was also tested vigorously and reports the correct line number. I'd guess the debugger remains the same no matter which document mode.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Microsoft Script Debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Script_Debugger), or [Internet Explorer Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28VS.85%29.aspx).

For complete list of what may be different in IE 8 from the older version consult with:

- [Internet Explorer 8 Readiness Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/readiness/developers-new.aspx) *(offical list)*
- especially [DOM Improvements](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/readiness/developers-new.aspx#dom)
- [JavaScript in Internet Explorer 8](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-in-internet-explorer-8/) *(John Resig's post)*

Also see [Web Bug Track](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/search/label/IE8) for possible quirks.

As a final note, doing `console.log` on every line may help you to find a particular bug in a hard way, but considering the amount of code you should really write unit test for modules. That's the only way you can make sure that your application will actually run with different inputs and conditions.

Comment: As mentioned, the messages given by IE don't really help so much in that case. Those come from the integrated debugger, and are reported because basically an object doesn't exist (where it should), meaning there probably was another error encountered before that failed silently.

Comment: see my update. I'm pretty sure msot of your problems are DOM related.

Comment: @galambalazs: unlikely at this stage of the RIA's rendering, as the errors start to happen while we still bootstrap and load dependencies. But that's possible, I'll have a look at your list and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: @galambalazs: definitely not DOM-related, it happens before changes to the DOM except for the dynamic dependency loading (which injects script nodes).

Comment: One more thing to note is that having no unit tests for 60k lines of code is shooting in the foot.

Comment: @galambalazs: doesn't really help me when the 60k lines don't belong to me though, does it? :)

Comment: It doesn't matter. Code should always be modular and testable. How can you ensure correct behavior otherwise? Functions should have clear purpose and so they can be tested one by one.

Comment: @galambalazs: O-kay... So what you're saying is that if your company dumps on you a new software project they inherited from someplace and it doesn't have units tests you are going to: a) implement all of them magically in a split second b) refuse to work ? I mean, thanks for the very valuable input which has not much to do with the question, we KNOW that software is supposed to be testable and modular, but if it isn't in the state I received it, it won't automagically happen overnight. Is your next answer going to be that it should just happen?

Comment: I didn't say "automagically" or "overnight" or "in a split second". Will your next comment be that I did? :) You're probably under pressure. I'm not your employer. I'm your common sense. :)